# How to avoid duplicate data in firebase Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing an Android application which I am using firebase (Realtime feature ) as a backend service. In addition, I have developed this function as it showing down below.

```
 private void checkUserExisting (){
    Dataa = mRef.getReference().child("Users");
    Dataa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                CreateUserProfile();
            }else {
                final String Uname = name.getText().toString().trim();
                final String Email = emailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                while (dataSnapshots.hasNext())
                {
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                    String EmailAddress = dataSnapshotChild.child("Email").toString();
                    String UserName = dataSnapshotChild.child("UserName").toString();
                    if (Uname.equals(UserName) || Email.equals(EmailAddress)){
                        Toast.makeText(Sgin_Up.this,"This user already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }else {
                        CreateUserProfile();
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Expansions**
The code is working pretty fine and it checks the existing data as well as it displays Toast message, but after data still get into the database, I want to void the duplication data.

Comment: Considering that email addresses are unique you could easily solve that issue with running single query which will check does `email` exists on database and during sign up prevent creating account with same email.

Comment: if ( dataSnapshotChild.child("Email").exists()){
                           
                    } is that can solve the issue @Yupi

Comment: The email Variable exists, I need to compare the data with the data that fill in in the sign-up stage if they much I have to through exception and prevent and avoid duplication data

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

When creating new account or sign up process you can check does user already exists for example:

```
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            boolean isNewUser = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser(); 
           //retruns true if user is new 
          //false if user exits, move on login screen/forgot password etc.

        }
    })
```

And you have prevented creating account with same email address which actually makes unnecessary checking does `email` address exists on database because it is not possible to create new account with same `email` address anymore.

If you still want to check existing of email address on database you can run simple query:

```
databaseReference.orderByChild("Email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent....
```

which will return data if email exists if not than there is no user with that email on database.

Comment: I am not using Firebase authentication feature , i do not think this will going to fit my issue

Answer (score 1):

You're now creating inside the loop. This means it happens, *each time* it finds a node that is not for that new user. This obviously isn't what you want, since the new profile should only be created if *none* of the nodes matches the new user. So it has to be outside of the loop:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    bool foundUser = false;
    final String Uname = name.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Email = emailAddress.getText().toString().trim();
    Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
    while (!foundUser && dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
        DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
        String EmailAddress = dataSnapshotChild.child("Email").toString();
        String UserName = dataSnapshotChild.child("UserName").toString();
        if (Uname.equals(UserName) || Email.equals(EmailAddress)){
            Toast.makeText(Sgin_Up.this,"This user already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            foundUser = true;
        }
    }

    if (!foundUser){
        CreateUserProfile();
    }
}
```

Comment: may I know from did you get FoundChildern variable

Comment: Woops.. that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Hi Frank, In this case, the function does not even check the entered data.

Comment: I (intentionally) changed nothing about that, but merely simplified the code and removed the superfluous writes. If you step through it now in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you'd expect it to do?